# javascript picture change not working correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, thumbnails, image

Im in the middle of creating a site and have run into a bit of an issue.  Basically what im working with is a collection of 3 pictures, two small, one large.  What I'd like is that when you click one of the small pictures, it takes the spot of the larger picture.  I have a javascript function that does this successfully but with one minor issue.  Theres 3 of these collections of 3 pictures and thus when you click a small image to have it swap with the bigger one, the small image takes the spot of all of all 3 of the larger images instead of just the one for its section.  Any suggestions?  Thanks

the javascript function

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('img').click(function(){
        var url = $(this).attr('src');
        var bigUrl = $(this).parents('.picture-container').find('.large-picture > img').attr('src');
        $('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
        $(this).attr('src', bigUrl);
        });
        });
```

what one of the sections looks like

```
 <div class = 'main-content'>
        <div class = 'picture-container'>
            <div class = 'large-picture' style = 'width:50%;height:100%;float:left;'>
                <img src = 'close_table_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
            </div>
            <div class = 'picture-content' style = 'float:right;width:45%;height:100%;'>
                <div class='picture-title'>BOUTIQUE PRODUCTION STUDIO</div>
                <div class='picture-text'>We built a boutique full service production studio that allows for one, two and three person filmed interviews and conversations. We have studio lights, a three camera set-up and remote monitoring. Additionally, our Infinity Wall creates a clean and professional look that allows the film to be about the message.</div>
                <div class = 'small-picture-wrapper'>
                    <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:left;height:100%;'>
                        <img src = 'hair_and_makeup_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                    </div>
                    <div class = 'small-picture' style = 'float:right;height:100%;'>
                        <img src = 'infinity_wall_dupontstudios.png' width = '100%' height = '100%'>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a class selector for `.large-picture` when you're selecting it to apply the new image src.  Presumably, all three sections have an element with this class, meaning all three are selected by your `.large-picture` selector. You need a more explicit selector to get ONLY the appropriate element.

You could use an id, or you could use `parents()` and `find()` in conjunction like you did previously:

```
$(this).parents('.picture-container').find('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! you'll have to forgive my ignorance tho, im still a bit confused.  so the code you gave me should use parents() to find the .large-picture that belongs to the same container?  where would I put this line?

Comment: Use this line to replace the line you have in your code where you're setting the image src:

`$('.large-picture > img').attr('src', url);`